# Switching to migrated tags in a monorepo

Tags: pipeline, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm in the process of moving a few existing projects to an NX monorepo using git subtree. I have also fetched tags from that remote respository so we preserve everything from the existing projects. With Subtree, I have moved these existing projects to their own directories like below:

```
- libs
  - project-A
  - project-B
- apps
  - project-c
<root level files of monorepo (eg: gitignore, readme etc..)>
```

However, if I switch to one of the migrated tags of "project-B" for example, the entire file structure changes to just having contents of "project-B" where I no longer see other projects or root level files I had for the monorepo. This makes sense technically, as it is the state of that tag but, this has become somewhat challenging if we want to make changes to an old version of "Project B" using tags. Like we have new pipeline YAML files in the root of monorepo that handles CI/CD expecting a certain file structure.

Are there any other solutions apart from creating a separate pipeline to handle these old migrated tags?